# executing on a remote machine

Tags: usb, serial-port, remote-access

**The Setup**

We have an aircon unit in the office but it takes a good hour to start cooling the place down, I have an IR USB device that communicates via a com port. I have a utility to send various IR codes to control an aircon unit.

I use .bat files to load the .exe and the .bin file

```
irtoy.exe -d COM4 -p -a 100 -f ACPowerToggle.bin
```

My question is what's the best way I can execute this on a remote server? Is it possible from a web server or something else?

Comment: what platform operating system does the remote server run on ? And why is this question tagged c++ ?

Comment: @AndreHolzner I would think this is a Windows Server, as it is using an exe file.

Comment: It'll probably be run on a old xp machine, the utility is built in c++, thought it might be relevant.

Comment: @Oliver9523, see my answer about SSH. It will do what you need, and a webserver is used to present sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using an [SSH server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) like [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/), as well as providing secure access, you can execute programs, manage everything needed as well as direct access to the computer's operating system.

**Edit:**

Yes, you can use both [iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt/id421507115?mt=8) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroidpro&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiYmVyc2Vya2VyLmFuZHJvaWQuYXBwcy5zc2hkcm9pZHBybyJd) apps to access your SSH server using a smart phone.

Comment: cheers, I'll have a look into SSH. Would this be easily accessible via a phone without having to build an app?

Comment: @Oliver9523 Absolutely, there are several iOS and Android apps to do that. See my answer edit for some examples.